# unresolved inclusion with any include files

Tags: c++, eclipse, inclusion

I'm getting an error running a Hello World Program using Eclipse. I have installed MinGW and Cygwin, I know I only need one but I have other editor that uses one but not the other.
I have checked the Paths and Symbols under GCC C++ Compiler, it links to directories which contain the include files. However, I am still getting an unresolved inclusion error on the include files. I'm using Windows 7. My Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <strings>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string yourName;

    cout << "Enter your name: ";
    cin >> yourName;
    cout << "Hello " << yourName << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the detailed error

```
Description                         Resource Path                   Location Type
Symbol 'cin' could not be resolved  test.c  /hello_world/src    line 17 Semantic Error
Symbol 'cout' could not be resolved test.c  /hello_world/src    line 16 Semantic Error
Symbol 'cout' could not be resolved test.c  /hello_world/src    line 18 Semantic Error
Symbol 'endl' could not be resolved test.c  /hello_world/src    line 18 Semantic Error
Type 'namespace' could not be resolved  test.c  /hello_world/src    line 10 Semantic Error
Type 'string' could not be resolved test.c  /hello_world/src    line 14 Semantic Error
```

Any help? thanks

Comment: There is a type `#include <strings>` should be `#include <string>`
Also try compiling with g++ instead of gcc

Comment: Did you create the project as `C` or `C++` project?

Comment: I originally had `include <string>`, but it didn't work. I still get the same type of error

Comment: Eclipse might try to compile "test.c" as C rather than C++ (if that's the name of your file). Try to rename your file "test.cpp".

Comment: @molbdnilo Renaming seems not sufficient (especially if the wrong project type was choosen - Eclipse then has already set up a tool chain with no C++ compiler)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you have selected to create a `C` project, in which case Eclipse sets up your tool chain to use the `C` compiler only.

Since you are using C++, you should create a `C++` project and create your source files with a `.cpp` extension.

You could also try to convert the existing `C` project into a `C++` project by adjusting the settings in the project properties, but it is usually easier to just create a new project and copy the files over (especially since you seem to just starting, and not have a big code base).

As you can see in the following picture, `SimpleC` has been created as `C`-project - there, your source code shows errors (even though I have renamed it to `.cpp`).

The `SimpleCpp` project was created as `C++` project - there, the source code does not show any errors.

[image]